# How to delete a category in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm intending to delete a Category in my database, I have succeeded in doing that by using Livewire Components but I'm trying to make it by using Controllers.
This is my Controller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;
use App\Models\Staff;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;
use DB;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    use WithPagination;
    public function deleteCategory($id)
    {
$category = Category::find($id);
$category->delete();
session()->flash('message', 'Category has been deleted successfully !');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::paginate(10);

        return view('form.categories', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
}
```

And here I have a blade(not Livewire's):

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
               <tr>
                      <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
                      <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
                      <td>{{$category->slug}}</td>
                      <td>
                      <a href="{{route('admin.editcategory', ['category_slug'=> $category->slug])}}"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></a>
                      <a href="#" onclick="confirm('Are you sure ,You want to delete this Category ?') || event.stopImmediatePropagation()" wire:click.prevent="deleteCategory({{$category->id}})"><i class="fa fa-times  text-danger"></i></a>
                      </td>
               </tr>
               @endforeach
```

Comment: What is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in a controller, you should have a link, instead of treating it as it was still a `LiweWire` component and calling the method directly. The `route()` call, will generate the URL you need and let your  tag link to that route.

```
<a href="{{route('category.delete', $category->id)}}" onclick="confirm('Are you sure ,You want to delete this Category ?') || event.stopImmediatePropagation()">
     <i class="fa fa-times  text-danger"></i>
</a>
```

For this to work you will need a route to actually trigger your delete method. In `web.php` routes file add that route.

```
Route::get('category/delete/{id}', [CategoriesController ::class, 'deleteCategory']);
```

For user experience, i would redirect back after it is deleted.

```
public function deleteCategory($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $category->delete();
    session()->flash('message', 'Category has been deleted successfully !');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**BE AWARE**

I would not consider this approach the best solution, usually you would do delete operations with the DELETE method on the `Http` call. As this seem to be your first step into Controllers, i think this will do fine, as doing DELETE methods in `Http` require forms.

Answer (score 0):

Create a route in your web.php file
Route::get(“deleteCategory/{id}”,[CategoriesController::class,” deleteCategory”)->name(“ deleteCategory”);

make the href of the a tag href=“{route(‘ deleteCategory’,$category->id)}”

ps
1-For the delete route it’s better to use form method delete instead of a get request

2-check also how to make a resource controller and resource routes in laravel